# Como tirar a seleção de um dropdownlist usando o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Não tenho tanto conhecimento do jQuery, gostaria de saber como tirar o atributo `selected` do dropdownlist usando o jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Com JavaScript nativo:

Com JS nativo tens de descobrir a `option` que está selecionada. Podes obter essa informação através do `select.selectedIndex`, que indica qual o index das options de um dado select que está selecionado.

Para encontrar e de-selecionar podes fazer assim:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
options[select.selectedIndex].removeAttribute("selected");
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7b0hgLx/

### Com jQuery:

O jQuery poupa algumas linhas e permite fazer assim:

```
$('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7b0hgLx/1

---

Fazendo `$('select').val('');` muda visualmente o estado mas o atributo ainda lá está.